# Tensorflow _pywrap_tf2 ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got the following error with TensorFlow:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

There are similar questions, but not with `_pywrap_tf2` and as far as I can see not with an easy working solution.

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to be what solved the problem:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0 --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, this really worked. I even reinstalled python then installed miniconda for this.

Answer (score 0):

For me this meant I needed to install VC distributable dll's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

I was able to see this was the problem by installing 2.12.0, then it spit out a useful error message, whereas 2.15 did not.

ref:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44110#issuecomment-711665582 and other answer