# Python Tenserflow/Chatgpts gymnasiam for deep reinforcement learning errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I dont understand these errors im getting can someone please explain it to me?

'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pacym\DRL_AERIATIONBASIN\pythonProject1\SQL.py", line 4, in 
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\pacym\DRL_AERIATIONBASIN\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 42, in 
from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
File "C:\Users\pacym\DRL_AERIATIONBASIN\pythonProject1.venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in 
from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: The specified module could not be found.
'''

Comment: Does this fix your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77582620/tensorflow-pywrap-tf2-importerror-dll-load-failed

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your installation. Try reinstalling tensorflow or one of the other helpful answers to this more active question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503603/tensorflow-on-windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could